# AS3 hide textInput from DateField

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flex3

is there a way to hide `textInput` from `DateField` in Action Script 3 ?
show result with only the icon.
with modifying the property `textInputStyleName="textInputStyle"` CSS :

```
.textInputStyle {
width : 0px ; //OR
display : none ;
}
```

Comment: You mean [`DateField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html) ?!

Comment: yes DateChooser from DateField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `TextInput` of your `DateField` component using `mx.core.mx_internal` like this :

```
var text_input:TextInput = date_field.mx_internal::getTextInput();
    text_input.visible = false;
```

You can also use a button to show a `DateChooser` component instead of a `DateField`.

Hope that can help.